# How to chain select_related functions in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following tables in my database:

```
class A(models.model):
   ...

class B(models.model):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.model):
   b = models.ForeignKey(B)
   data = models.TextField(max_length=50)
```

What I want to do is get the `C` object with a pk of 215, and select the related `B` object, and also select the related `A` object of the `B` object. Right now, what I am doing is this:

```
c = Models.objects.select_related('b').select_related('a').get(pk=215)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'a'. Choices are: b
```

Is this possible to actually get all 3 objects with just one database hit? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
c = Models.objects.select_related('b__a').get(pk=215)
```

Note the double underscore.

See the section starting with `You can follow foreign keys...` under https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related